# Can I ghost/image my jailbroken AppleTV?

Tags: jailbreak, appletv

I have an AppleTV2 (4.4.3) which I have jailbroken and am running XBMC on.  I want to upgrade it to 4.4.4 so it can support mirroring, and jailbreak again, but advice on the internets is split about whether XBMC will run reliably on 4.4.4, so in an ideal world I'd like to create an image of my current setup so I can restore it somehow if 4.4.4 doesn't make the grade.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Essentially, no, you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this because even if you backed up your ATV2, Apple recently (or a while ago)  implemented a feature which disables users to downgrade their iPhone/iPad/ATV2 firmware.  The best bet would be to wait until there is a reliable build of XBMC for the 4.4.4 update.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Cheeky beggars.  I think I'll just take the risk - what use are toys if you don't play with them eh?  Thanks for the answer.